# Batch file won't put strings from text file into variables (code included)

Tags: windows, batch, code

The program searches for files containing certain keywords and a part of it's task is to display the keywords being searched. The keywords are written one below the other in a text file that it reads from. However, it only reads from the last line? Probably a very simple error but I'm missing it...

```
@echo off
:main_section
set main_dir=%cd%
set key1=variable    
set key2=variable
set key3=variable
set key4=variable
set key5=variable
for /f "delims=" %%a in (keylist.txt) do set "key1=%%a"
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%b in (keylist.txt) do set "key2=%%b"
for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%c in (keylist.txt) do set "key3=%%c"
for /f "skip=3 delims=" %%d in (keylist.txt) do set "key4=%%d"
for /f "skip=4 delims=" %%e in (keylist.txt) do set "key5=%%e"
echo warning: do not launch from the userprofile directory
echo warning: write exactly five keywords in keylist.txt
echo searching for %key1%, %key2%, %key3%, %key4%, %key5%
pushd collection 
>>%key1%.txt findstr /i /p /s %key1% %userprofile%\*.* >nul
echo search for %key1% complete - printed to collection\%key1%.txt
>>%key2%.txt findstr /i /p /s %key2% %userprofile%\*.* >nul
echo search for %key2% complete - printed to collection\%key2%.txt
>>%key3%.txt findstr /i /p /s %key3% %userprofile%\*.* >nul
echo search for %key3% complete - printed to collection\%key3%.txt
>>%key4%.txt findstr /i /p /s %key4% %userprofile%\*.* >nul
echo search for %key4% complete - printed to collection\%key4%.txt
>>%key5%.txt findstr /i /p /s %key5% %userprofile%\*.* >nul
echo search for %key5% complete - printed to collection\%key5%.txt
pushd %main_dir% 
for /f "tokens=3" %%f in ('dir "collection"^|find "File(s)"') do set size=%%f
set "size=%size:,=%"
echo %size% bytes of information collected
echo press any key to exit the program
pause >nul
```

Comment: Remove (`rem`) the `@echo off` and run your batch file. You will see your mistake. Hint: The first `for` loop processes all the lines in `keylist.txt`. The next `for` loop processes the last four lines ...

Comment: I rarely use the for /f to read lines, so I guess I thought skip=3 means skipping the first three lines and reading the fourth, instead of everything below 3. Is there a way to stop it from doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Probably a very simple error but I'm missing it...

Your `for` loops are processing all of the lines in the file so only the last value in the file is stored.

You can simplify your batch file and use a single `for` loop together with [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and a counter.

Here is a small batch file that gives you the basic solution. Combine this with your batch file.

**test.cmd:**

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a _index=1
for /f "delims=" %%a in (keylist.txt) do (
  set "key!_index!=%%a"
  set /a _index+=1
  )
echo searching for !key1!, !key2!, !key3!, !key4!, !key5!
endlocal
```

**Example output:**

```
> type keylist.txt
1
2
3
4
5
> test
searching for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) - Conditionally perform a command several times.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.